# Difference between t.foo and t[foo] in Lua

Tags: indexing, lua, lua-table

Given a table

```lua
t = {foo = "bar", bar = "foo"}
```

and a variable

```lua
foo = "bar"
```

what's the difference between

```lua
print(t.foo)
```

which prints "bar" and

```lua
print(t[foo])
```

which prints "foo"

Answer (score 3):

`t[expr]` is the indexing operation, where `t` is the table to be indexed and `expr` is the expression of which the value is used as key. `t[foo]` thus evaluates to `t["bar"]`. The value for the key `bar` is the string `foo`. Thus `print(t[foo])` prints "foo".

`t.name` is merely a shorthand for `t["name"]` where name matches Lua's lexical convention for an identifier:

> Names (also called identifiers) in Lua can be any string of Latin letters, Arabic-Indic digits, and underscores, not beginning with a digit and not being a reserved word. Identifiers are used to name variables, table fields, and labels.
> - [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1)

*This means that `name` is not evaluated as the expression `name` but rather as the string literal `"name"` when indexing the table.* Thus `t.foo` is equivalent to `t["foo"]` which evaluates to `bar`.

**TL;DR:** To index tables with the variables of values or other expressions, use `t[expr]`. In particular you must use `t[index]` to index the list part of tables. You also have to use `t[expr]` if `expr` is a string literal that does not qualify as an identifier (ex: `t["foo-bar"]`). To index tables with keys that are names / identifiers, use `t.name`.