# Get index of table Lua from string input

Tags: lua, lua-table

Suppose I have the following:

```
table = {a = {1, 2}, b = {3, 4}}
input = "a" -- abstracted away; it's a RV from another function.
```

You can use `table.a[1]` to get 1; however, I want to get it from the input variable - which is the return value of another function that I have, which returns the string `"a"` and not just `a`.

Now, this is where the error from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73507953/index-dictionary-table-within-table-lua) comes into play:

[image]

When I did `table[input]`, it returned a table object, so then when I tried `table[input][1]`, it had the calling a table error.

Is it possible to get 1 using indexing with the input `"a"`? If so, could someone let me know how this works? Thanks!

Comment: It simply is not possible to get an `attempting to call table` error with this. The only call expression/statement here is the `print`, which obviously is not a table.

Comment: Additionally, please format code using three backticks. Some reproducing steps would definitely be nice, because there aren't enough details.

Comment: try this table :  `table = {a = {1, 2}, b = {3, 4}, input = {5, 6} }`  and you will understand everything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between t.foo and t\[foo\] in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085668/difference-between-t-foo-and-tfoo-in-lua)

Answer (score 0):

for any table if you use `.` to index it, it will use a **string** index. 
When you use `[]` to index it, this means you can use **any** sort of datatype and it allows you to also use variables.

```lua
local someTable = {
    a = "hello",
    b = "world"
    c = "!"
}

-- I can do
print(someTable.a) -- prints "hello"

-- and
print(someTable["b"]) -- prints "world"

-- however
print(someTable[c]) -- will error since there is no c variable

------

-- note that this would be valid
local someVariable = "c"
print(someTable[someVariable]) -- prints "!"
```

---

Going back to your case. `tbl1` is using `[]` and using the **variable** input. However `tbl2` is using the **string** `"input"` as the index in your table. Your table does not contain `"input"` as a key, so it returns nil

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly, I apologize if not. If you want to, for example, send a specific part of a table to a user after they specified which key of the table they want then you're already doing everything correctly.

The `tbl1` table contains the key "a" part of the main table. You can't print a table, but you can either print specific values by using `tbl1[number]` or do this:

```
table = {a = {1, 2}, b = {3, 4}}
input = "b"
tbl1 = table[input]

for _, v in pairs(table) do
    print(v)
end

-- Expected output:
-- 3
-- 4
```