# Access specific variable in for k,v in pairs based on the user input

Tags: lua, key-value

I have been trying to figure out how to access a variable from within a table based on a sting that the user inputs but have been unable to make it work. How do I collect the specified value using a string? The intent is to enable the user to grab the specific value off the table based on their input, the table itself will not always have the same values to work with (eg. the table may change from t={a=1,b=2} to t={z=1,v=3} or any other iteration based off initial table selection).

The code I have been trying to use is as follows:

```
local user_input = "a"
local table = {a = 1, b = 2}

for k, v in pairs(table) do
  print(v.user_input)
end
```

The desired value = 1 but it returns NIL instead. I understand that print(v.a) would return the desired value, but I am looking for a way to grab different information based on the user input. I have tried the following but have been unsuccessful as they do not return the desired value:

```
local user_input = "a"
local table = {a = 1, b = 2}

for k, v in pairs(table) do
  local item = tostring("v." ..user_input)
  print(item)
end
---------------------------
local user_input = "a"
local table = {a = 1, b = 2}

for k, v in pairs(table) do
  local item = tostring("v." ..user_input)
  print(_G[item])
end
```

Comment: What do you think `tostring` and `pairs` do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between t.foo and t\[foo\] in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085668/difference-between-t-foo-and-tfoo-in-lua)

Answer (score 1):

> I have been trying to figure out how to access a variable from within a table based on a sting that the user inputs

I am not sure to understand the issue, but the given requirement is pretty trivial.

```
user_input = "a"
table = {a = 1, b = 2}

print(table[user_input])
```

This will print "1".

---

If there is a more complicated table, it might change a little bit:

```
user_input = "a"
table = {
  a = { "a", "b" },
  b = { "c", "d" }
}

for k,v in pairs(table[user_input]) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

It will get the sub-table associated to the key "a" and will print:

```
1       a
2       b
```