# Prototypes(OOP) - Can I Have Parameters in Object Functions?

Tags: oop, lua, prototype

Thanks for reading this post.

I'm working with Lua object prototypes as described by lua.org and tutorialspoint. However, I'm having some problems working with parameters passed to an object's function. Most likely, I am failing to understand some aspect of objects in Lua.

What I want is a function that lets me call upon any value stored in the object at the specified key.

something like:

```
function Class:getValue(key)
   print(self.key)
end
```

But this prints nil if I attempt object:getValue(key).

So far, I have the following code:

```
Gmenu = {zIndex=1,name="Menu",options=menuMain,optNum=3,xPos=0,yPos=0,width=30,height=90} 

function Gmenu:new(o,zIndex,name,options,xPos,yPos,width,height)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index=self
    self.zIndex=zIndex or 1
    self.name=name or "none"
    self.options=options or {}
    self.optNum=#options or 0   
    self.xPos=xPos or 0
    self.yPos=yPos or 0
    self.width=width or 0
    self.height=height or 0
    return o
end

function Gmenu:getParam(param) -- returns value at specified key in object
    if type(self.param) == table then
        printTable(self.param)
    else
        print(self.param)
    end
end

        xTest = Gmenu:new(nil,1,"Test Menu",menuBattle,50,50,100,120) 
        xTest:getParam(name)
        xTest:getParam(options)
        print(xTest.name)
```

The results I get from the last 3 lines of code are:

```
nil
nil
Test Menu
```

So a direct reference to the object's key yields the value, but self.name does not. Why is this the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between t.foo and t\[foo\] in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085668/difference-between-t-foo-and-tfoo-in-lua)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't think it answers my question because I think I'm calling my class functions incorrectly, or I'm missing out on something.

To clarify, I followed this tutorial here:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_object_oriented.htm 

The first example shows a class function at the bottom of the first example: Creating A Simple Class. I see that none of the class functions they create and use have arguments in them, but that is what I am attempting to do.

Comment: well let me be more specific, you give the example of `function Class:getValue(key)
   print(self.key)
end` this `self.key` should be `self[key]` where `key` is some string you want to index the table `self` with. you also make a similar mistake here `xTest:getParam(name)` this should be `xTest:getParam("name")`

Comment: `if type(self.param) == table then`
type() returns a string, you should be comparing against `"table"` rather than `table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the body of `:new` function `self` is a class, and `o` is an instance being created.

Assigning to `self.zIndex` modifies the field of class, this is not what you need.
To initialize the instance field, you should use `o.zIndex=zIndex or 1` instead.
When accessing `xTest.name`, `name` field is absent in the instance `xTest`, so Lua fallbacks to reading the field `name` from its class, where it does exist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was basically the answer, along with the fact I was calling variables in the getParam function instead of strings.